# Comment line command that inserts // at the start of the line, not indented

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default, commenting a line in Visual Studio Code (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>) adds the `//` such that it is indented as far as the code being commented.

I prefer seeing code comments blocked out at the margin (column zero). Is there a way to configure this behaviour?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to configure this. I see two options here: 1. Submit a feature request; 2. Create your own extension for this.

Comment: I added [a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20515).